# How do I stop an auto typer from ‘pyramiding’?

Tags: vbscript

I’ve been looking around for an auto-typer for some fun on Discord and I found a Virtual Basic code on Youtube that functions mostly to my needs but it has one problem. It’s supposed to type a phrase and then enter and then type and enter for a set amount of times but when I test it in notepad++ it does this:

test

testtest

testtesttest

testtesttesttest

And so on until it maxes out at 17.  I’m not sure what could be wrong with it because I didn’t make it and I’m not very adept with coding at all.  This is the code:

```
set shell = createobject(“wscript.shell”)

strtext = inputbox(“What would you like the message to be?”)

strtimes = inputbox(“How many times would you like to type it?”)

if not isnumeric(strtimes) then

lol=msgbox(“Please write a number next time”)

wscript.quit

end if

msgbox “After you click Ok the message will start in 2 seconds”

wscript.sleep(2000)

for i=1 to strtimes

shell.sendkeys (strtext & “”)

shell.sendkeys (“{Enter}”)

wscript.sleep(100)

next
```

I’ve tried adjusting spaces and such before and after parentheses  but nothing seems to change the ‘pyramid’ outcome.  Any suggestions on what I could try to change or if anyone actually sees what’s wrong would be much appreciated.

Comment: The problem is you want to use it with Discord but your testing it in Notepad++ don't expect one program to work the same as another. The only true test is to use Discord, you find other issues when using Discord that a different to Notepad++ entirely.

Answer (score 0):

The Issue you are running into is with notepad++ specifically.

```
shell.sendkeys (“{Enter}”)
```

Is triggering the Word Auto Completion.

[image: Word Auto Completion]

I ran this writing to standard Notepad without issue.

**Edit:**

This does work in Notepad++ if you do the Enter twice.

```
shell.sendkeys ("{Enter}") 
shell.sendkeys ("{Enter}")
```

Or if you add a space after the string.

```
shell.sendkeys (strtext & " ")
```